# how to add a new record UI in ember

Tags: ember.js

Just when I think that I'm getting a handle on ember, this happens and I run into a brick wall.

I have

```
App.Router.map(function() {

this.resource('customers', function() {
    this.resource('customer', {
        path : ':customer_id'
    });
```

customers route :

```
App.CustomersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
    return this.store.find('customer');
},
```

customer controller :

```
App.CustomerController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
needs: ['state'],
isEditing: false,
isNotEditing: Ember.computed.not('isEditing'),

actions : {

    startEditing: function() {
        this.set('isEditing',true);
        this.set('validationErrors', '');
    },

    save: function() {
```

and these templates :

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customers">
 ...
 {{outlet}}
  ...
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customer">
...
{{#if isEditing}}
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <a class="btn btn-success" {{action save}}>Save</a>
            <a class="btn btn-warning" {{action cancel}}>Cancel</a>
        </div>
      {{else}}
        <div class="well well-sm">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" {{action startEditing}}>Edit</a>
            <a class="btn btn-danger" {{action delete}}>Remove</a>
        </div>
{{/if}}
```

this is all working well for me. I can select a customer, press the edit button, form inputs get enabled, press the save button and changed data is persistent back to the db

*however* : this is my brick wall.

How do I enable a feature to create a new record : I dont want to duplicate the edit form,  just show blanks

I am assuming that I need to put "new" into the router map

```
this.resource('customers', function() {
  this.resource('customer', {
path : ':customer_id'
});

route('new');
 });
```

but do I create a CustomerNew controller and CustomerNew route and CustomerNew template ?

I have put an action into the customers controller

```
<a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs pull-right" {{action startNew}}>New</a>
```

do I really need to create a route & controller & template just to handle the new action ? Or can I reuse the customer/1 route/controller/template ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do things The Ember Way (TM) you'd want to use a new route, controller, and template.  Ember does make it easy to consolidate your logic and not have to duplicate code.  In templates you can do this with `partial`, and in your JS code you can do it with `Ember.Mixin`.

Here's a JSBin of the general idea : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1056/edit

Here's the interesting parts of the templates :

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customers/new">
    Add a new customer<br/>
    {{partial "customers/form"}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customer/edit">
    Edit a customer<br/>
    {{partial "customers/form"}}
  </script>
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="customers/_form">
    {{input value=name}}
    <button {{action save}}>Save</button>
    <button {{action cancel}}>Cancel</button>
  </script>
```

And then the controllers :

```
App.CrudController = Ember.Mixin.create({
  actions : {
    save : function(){
      this.get('model').save();
      this.transitionToRoute('customers');
    },
    cancel : function(){
      this.get('model').rollback();
      this.transitionToRoute('customers');
    }
  }
});

App.CustomersNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(App.CrudController,{});

App.CustomerEditController = Ember.ObjectController.extend(App.CrudController,{});
```

Comment: nice. very nice. I particularly like the Ember.Mixin bit